# Select N rows in the reverse order from a huge MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select N rows in the reverse order from a huge MySQL table.

```
CREATE TABLE fitness (
  user int unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  health int unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  ts int unsigned DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8
```

There are indexes in the table, not shown here. This table holds millions of entries overall and a few hundred thousand entries for each `user`.

I need to fetch rows in the reverse order sorted by `ts`, like below.

```
mysql> select * from fitness where user=1 and ts < 1234567 order by ts desc limit 100;
```

This works. However, this query is super slow since it need to fetch all the matching records, sort and give top 100 results. There could be a few hundred thousand matching records for `user=1 and ts < 1234567` and hence above query is slow.

Any suggestions how to do it better?

Comment: you could use: [CREATE INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html)  on the fields `user, ts`. (1 index on 2 fields)

Comment: There are indexes, not shown here. It's not about index, there might be few hundred thousand entries matching the condition.

Comment: If you do not give all the information, your question is not good, improve your question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64475678/edit)

Comment: "There are indexes, not shown here." and the claim "It's not about index".  But i am sure query time will decrease when adding this index.

Comment: Is there some lower bound on *ts* that you can put in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @Luuk Please stop suggesting something which does work. If you sort hundreds of thousands of rows for every query even with indexes, you really haven't worked with large tables

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc well, the bound is N (100 in example). Since ts is not continuous, I can't calculate lower bound

Comment: @Rahul If there are indexes, then it's decidedly odd not to share those.

Comment: See https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/. And note that the actions you have taken do not amount to 'closing' the question.

Answer (score 1):

according your question title the query your running the result is OK, but your asking the faster query which need another question.. but in mysql getting faster result you should use indexing which your already mention..still if your query is looking slow. the first thing you should is use `EXPLAIN` to know the timing of speed.

second thing you should do is indexing `FORCE INDEX`  Mysql doc.

> The FORCE INDEX hint acts like USE INDEX (index_list), with the addition that a table scan is assumed to be very expensive. In other words, a table scan is used only if there is no way to use one of the named indexes to find rows in the table.

so change your select query with force indexing.

```
mysql> select * 
from fitness 
FORCE INDEX (index_name)
where user=1 and ts < 1234567 order by ts desc limit 100;
```

here is a good post by [Henrik Peinar](https://blog.nodeswat.com/making-slow-queries-fast-with-composite-indexes-in-mysql-eb452a8d6e46)

Answer (score 0):

Create an index for user and ts. Even it these are int, the index will improve the query.

Comment: indexes does not help much, there could be a few hundred thousand matching records for user=1 and ts < 1234567 and each time it need to sort it even with indexes

Comment: The index (on both fields) will pre-sort the data. Ensure the index is actually on both fields, so should be able to seek and read. Try it with the index User and ts, but ts descending. Also consider including the other field (health) so it's a covering index.

Comment: @seanb as I mentioned, there could be a few hundred thousand matching records for "user=1 and ts < 1234567". So even with indexes, it need to sort all the rows which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Create the index on `user` and `ts` - as per other answers. Consider creating a full covering index so it doesn't need to go back to the original table e.g., `create index IX_test on fitness (user, ts, health).`

You may get better performance making ts descending ... but it shouldn't matter e.g., `create index IX_test on fitness (user, ts desc, health).`

Ensure your index on on `user` first then `ts`; it means it can seek straight to the user and appropriate position (the data will *already be sorted appropriately* so won't need a new sort). If it's `ts` first then `user`, it needs to do a whole lot of filtering to get the data out.

Update:
I did put an example here to demononstrate but was on SQL Server. It showed that the index worked very well - but it may confuse people/put people on red-herring-path so I removed it.